# Trigger not handling transactions initiated in parallel thru JMeter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing an issue wherein thru JMeter if I try to insert same record from two different transactions and at the same time (even the same second) then duplicate records appear in a table temp_tab . Even though we have trigger deployed to to avoid duplicate records getting inserted into temp_tab table. Due to design limitation we cannot use constraints on this table.

Need your valuable suggestion on this issue.

Below is the trigger code

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO row_c
            FROM temp_tab
           WHERE offer_id = oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).offer_id
             AND view_id != oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).view_id
             AND offer_inst_id != oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).offer_inst_id
             AND subscr_no = oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).subscr_no
             AND subscr_no_resets = oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).subscr_no_resets
             AND view_status IN (view_types.cPENDING, view_types.cCURRENT)
             AND disconnect_reason IS NULL
             AND ((oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).active_dt >= active_dt AND
                  (oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).active_dt < inactive_dt OR inactive_dt IS NULL)) OR
                  (oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).active_dt < active_dt AND
                   (oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).inactive_dt IS NULL OR
                    oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).inactive_dt > active_dt)));

           IF row_c > 0 THEN
              oiv_pkg.trig_tab.DELETE;
              raise_application_error (-20001, '269901, TRIG: INSERT Failed: OID: ' || oiv_pkg.trig_tab(idx).offer_inst_id ');
           END IF;
```

Comment: How could a trigger prevent duplicate rows in the absence of a constraint?  Are you doing something like explicitly locking a row in some other table in order to attempt to serialize access?  Using `dbms_lock`?

Comment: Justin, the only thing I found in the trigger is the above logic to handdle duplicates. No locking mechanism. Could you pls suggest?

Comment: What is `temp_tab`?  How is `oiv_pkg.trig_tab` populated?  Is this table defined on `temp_tab`?  What sort of trigger is it?  A row-level trigger?  A statement-level trigger?  Before or after?  It looks like you may be posting code from one trigger of multiple triggers.  But this logic would not prevent different sessions from inserting duplicate data.  If you want to do that, you'd need to implement some sort of locking that will serialize access.  That, of course, will radically decrease the scalability of your application.

Comment: If you care about performance, I'd strongly question the "design limitation" that prevents you from using constraints.

Comment: Can you me give me an example of locking mechaism which can be implemented to serialize access? I know the current design looks weird but this is waht the architect has explained to me. My role is to correct it now :)

Comment: oiv_pkg.trig_tab gets initiallized and populated by the FE application before insert begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to prevent duplicates without using the proper solution, a constraint, you'd need to implement some sort of locking mechanism.  In this example, I'll create a table `foo` with a single column `col1` and create a couple of triggers that ensure that the data in `col1` is unique.  In order to do this, I'm introducing a new table that exists just to have its single row locked to provide a serialization mechanism.  Note that I'm only handling insert operations, I'm ignoring updates that create duplicates.  I'm also simplifying the problem by not bothering to track which rows are inserted in row-level triggers in order to make the final check more efficient.  Of course, serializing `insert` operations on your table will absolutely crush you application's scalability.

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> create table make_application_slow(
  2    dummy varchar2(1)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into make_application_slow values( 'A' );

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace trigger trg_foo_before_stmt
  2    before insert on foo
  3  declare
  4    l_dummy varchar2(1);
  5  begin
  6    -- Ensure that only one session can ever be inserting data
  7    -- at any time.  This is a great way to turn a beefy multi-core
  8    -- server into a highly overloaded server with one effective
  9    -- core.
 10    select dummy
 11      into l_dummy
 12      from make_application_slow
 13       for update;
 14* end;
SQL> /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_foo_after_stmt
  2    after insert on foo
  3  declare
  4    l_cnt pls_integer;
  5  begin
  6    select count(*)
  7      into l_cnt
  8      from( select col1, count(*)
  9              from foo
 10             group by col1
 11            having count(*) > 1 );
 12
 13    if( l_cnt > 0 )
 14    then
 15      raise_application_error( -20001, 'Duplicate data in foo is not allowed.' );
 16    end if;
 17  end;
 18  /
```

Now, if you try to insert data with the same `col1` value in two different sessions, the second session will block indefinitely waiting for the first session to commit (or rollback).  That prevents duplicates but it is generally hideously inefficient.  And if there is any possibility that a user would be able to walk away from an active transaction, your DBA will curse you for building an application that forces them to constantly kill sessions when someone locks up the entire application because they went to lunch without committing their work.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the solution. I think I should better force the architects to consider changin the design of our application.